# O que é WRAP e UNWRAP?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estudando um pouco de tuplas não consegui entender WRAP e UNWRAP pois a explicação não estava muito concisa.Portanto o que é WRAP e UNWRAP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**WRAP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn878066.aspx)

Segundo a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn878066.aspx):

> The WRAP operation supports encryption of a symmetric key using a key
>   encryption key that has previously been stored in an Azure Key Vault.
>
> The WRAP operation is only strictly necessary for symmetric keys
>   stored in Azure Key Vault since protection with an asymmetric key can
>   be performed using the public portion of the key. This operation is
>   supported for asymmetric keys as a convenience for callers that have a
>   key-reference but do not have access to the public key material.

Ou seja, ela suporta criptografia de uma chave simétrica usando uma chave de criptografia que foi armazenada anteriormente em um *Azure Key Vault*. Ela é estritamente necessária apenas para chaves simétricas armazenadas no *Azure Key Vault*, uma vez que a proteção com uma chave assimétrica pode ser executada usando a parte pública da chave. Esta operação é suportada para chaves assimétricas como uma conveniência para chamadores que têm uma referência de chave mas não têm acesso ao material de chave pública.

A rotina Wrapper tem a finalidade de criptografar o código-fonte de tal forma que somente o Oracle tenha condições de ler e compilar o texto gerado. Algumas de suas características são:

- Converte o código-fonte de PL/SQL em uma forma intermediária de "código-objeto".
- "Código-objeto" gerado é portável como se fosse o próprio fonte.
- O compilador PL/SQL reconhece e carrega o código gerado pelo Wrapper automaticamente.

Essa rotina impede que o código-fonte seja manuseado por outros desenvolvedores, além disso, por se tratar de uma versão de código portável, é independe de plataforma. As referências a variáveis `Bind` externas são resolvidas a tempo de carga e os processos de `Import/Export` normais aceitam arquivos gerados pela rotina `Rappel`. Fazendo dessas as principais vantagens da Wrapper.

Porém, ela não consegue trabalhar com o bloco de PL/SQL por completo, englobando todas as funções da linguagem, apenas com alguns comandos específicos:

- `Create Procedure`
- `Create Functions`
- `Create Package`
- `Create Package body`

Linha de código da WRAP:

```
wrap iname=ra_ex.sql oname=ra_ex_s.plb
```

[**UNWRAP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn878079.aspx)

Segundo a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/Dn878079.aspx):

> The UNWRAP operation supports decryption of a symmetric key using the
>   target key encryption key. This operation is the reverse of the WRAP
>   operation.
>
> The UNWRAP operation applies to asymmetric and symmetric keys stored
>   in Azure Key Vault since it uses the private portion of the key

Essa operação suporta a descriptografia de uma chave simétrica usando a chave de criptografia de chave de destino. Ela é o inverso da operação WRAP. A operação UNWRAP se aplica a chaves assimétricas e simétricas armazenadas no *Azure Key Vault*, uma vez que utiliza a parte privada da chave.

O exemplo é retirado do livro Introdução a sistemas de bancos de dados, do C. J. Date. Considere as tuplas:

> T1:
>
> ```
> TUPLE {
>       NOME NOME, ENDE TUPLE{
>                   RUA CHAR, CIDADE CHAR,
>                     ESTADO CHAR, CEP CHAR}
>     }
> ```
>
> T2:
>
> ```
> TUPLE {NOME NOME, RUA CHAR, CIDADE CHAR,
> ESTADO CHAR, CEP CHAR}
> ```
>
> O tipo `T1` inclui um atributo que, por si só, é de algum tipo de
>   tupla. Agora considere `NENDE1` e `NENDE2` como variáveis de tupla dos
>   tipos `T1` e `T2`.
>
> A expressão:
>
> ```
> NENDE2 WRAP{RUA, CIDADE, ESTADO, CEP} AS ENDE
> ```
>
> Pega o valor atual de `NENDE2` e empacota(wrap) os componentes `RUA`,
>   `CIDADE`, `ESTADO` e `CEP` desse valor para gerar um único componente
>   `ENDE` com o valor da tupla. Logo o resultado da expressão é do tipo
>   `T1` e, portanto, a atribuição a seguir é válida:
>
> ```
> NENDE1 := NENDE2 WRAP {RUA, CIDADE, ESTADO, CEP} AS ENDE;
> ```
>
> A expressão:
>
> ```
> NENDE1 UNWRAP ENDE
> ```
>
> Pega o valor atual de `NENDE1` e desempacota(unwrap) os componentes
>   `ENDE` (com valor da tupla) desse valor para gerar quatro componentes
>   separados `RUA`, `CIDADE`, `ESTADO` e `CEP`. Logo o resultado da
>   expressão é do tipo `T2` e, portanto, a atribuição a seguir é válida:
>
> ```
> NENDE2 := NENDE1 UNWRAP ENDE;
> ```

Referências:

- [PL/SQL Wrapper](http://www.devmedia.com.br/pl-sql-wrapper/4636)
- [PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage)
- [Wrapper](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/2608/oracle/wrapper?trace=1519021197&source=single)
- Livro: Introdução a sistemas de bancos de dados - C.J. Date